# Querying property of sub-entity with hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to build a query with Hibernate Criteria.

I have two tables (Table A and Table B) and they are MANY - TO - MANY connected.

Table B has a property, id, that I would like to query to filter for Table A.

**So for example :**

This is my TableA class referencing TableB:

```
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
  @JoinTable(name = "tableb", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = DATABASE_COLUMN_ID, nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(
      name = TABLE_B, nullable = true, updatable = false) })
  private Set<TableB> tableB;
```

I want to query all Table A´s that have one Table B with the id of 123.

The code that I wanted to write was something like this:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "some name"));
...
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("tableB.id", "123"));
```

Unfortunately I do get an Exception like this:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: tableB.id of: TableA.
```

Who knows what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create alias on tableB and then use the criteria. Something like criteria.createAlias("tableB", "tableb");

then use criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("tableb.id", "123"));

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer. I will try that ... What exactly does createAlias do ?